# Cassandra cpu high usage

Tags: cassandra

I'm runnging a six nodes cluster

there is one node, that behaves different than other nodes with high cpu usage

I found WARN in system.log showed that a lot of tombstone cell were queried.

meanwhile, using the jvm-tools , shows some sharedpool-worker with high cpu usage

FYI I using the tools introduces here: 
https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### update

I've seen a lot of tombstone reads, maybe it is related to high cpu usage?
I think it it about the data model design

```
CREATE TABLE ecoboost_visit.visit (
enterprise_id int,
id text,
app_name text,
app_version text,
appkey text,
browser_family text,
browser_version text,
browser_version_string text,
city text,
country text,
created_on timestamp,
device_brand text,
device_family text,
device_model text,
device_token text,
first_visit_page_domain_by_session text,
first_visit_page_source_by_session text,
first_visit_page_source_domain_by_session text,
first_visit_page_source_keyword_by_session text,
first_visit_page_source_url_by_session text,
first_visit_page_title_by_session text,
first_visit_page_url_by_session text,
ip text,
isp text,
net_type text,
os_category text,
os_family text,
os_language text,
os_timezone text,
os_version text,
os_version_string text,
platform text,
province text,
resolution text,
sdk_image_url text,
sdk_name text,
sdk_source text,
sdk_version text,
track_id text,
ua_string text,
PRIMARY KEY (enterprise_id, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.1
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"0"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'sstable_size_in_mb': '64', 'tombstone_threshold': '.2',     'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression':   'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

I used this table to track visits log, every `ent` means a website

[image]
[image]

Here is the GC INfo

```
INFO  [Service Thread] 2016-04-02 07:38:16,554 GCInspector.java:278 -    ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 225ms.  CMS Old Gen: 5640515840 -> 2868732344; Par Eden Space: 16464 -> 418333648; Par Survivor Space: 5774976 -> 3817304
INFO  [Service Thread] 2016-04-03 07:08:27,224 GCInspector.java:278 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 209ms.  CMS Old Gen: 5637562768 -> 2887903056; Par Eden Space: 6704 -> 2306495144;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2016-04-06 06:34:18,908 GCInspector.java:278 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 225ms.  CMS Old Gen: 5642735152 -> 3061550896; Par Eden Space: 8547280 -> 644954400; Par Survivor Space: 6253328 -> 2236696
INFO  [Service Thread] 2016-04-07 06:03:13,598 GCInspector.java:278 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 221ms.  CMS Old Gen: 5638070792 -> 3173030976; Par Eden Space: 670736 -> 683574904; Par Survivor Space: 2089552 -> 2448848
INFO  [Service Thread] 2016-04-12 10:38:15,825 GCInspector.java:278 - ParNew GC in 7860ms.  CMS Old Gen: 5331043280 -> 5331554336; Par Eden Space: 2577006592 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 2984416 -> 25906264
```

Comment: Thank you for the jvm-tools link. I have high CPU load with no reads/writes. It turned out to be caused by Prometheus. I opted it out and load went to zero.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear what's going on - seeing the output of `nodetool tpstats` would give us an idea of the workload you're currently running (read heavy? write heavy? counters?). Without that, we can guess:

If you have one node that's misbehaving of 6, it's possible that all of your clients are somehow stuck to that one node. If you have RF=3 as is typical, you would expect 3 nodes to misbehave (indicating a data hot spot). What's your `replication_factor` for your keyspace?

You have quite a few columns. It's not enough to point the finger and say "this is wrong", but it's a fair bit. If you update one column at a time, that schema may make sense. If you always write a full row at a time, you will likely get better performance if you serialize the data yourself into a JSON or similar blob, and write it as an opaque column.

With `tombstone_threshold` of 0.2, you'll likely re-compact sstables pretty frequently if you're overwriting. Given your tombstone messages, I suspect you're creating a number of tombstones - is your node busy compacting? What's `nodetool compactionstats` say? If you're busy compacting, you can tune this by either throttling compaction throughput or reducing the number of concurrent_compactors.

With a 5.9GB compacted partition, and 2.6GB/s of heap allocation, what you're likely seeing is that [when Cassandra reads from a CQL partition, it has to deserialize the index segments to find the relevant parts of the partition for the slice you've requested](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9754). Doing so creates a LOT of java garbage - if you're using ParNew/CMS, you'll often blow out new generation and see a very frequent ParNew times as you fill+promote to old gen, and then depending on how much space you have, you may fill old gen and see very long collections as you collect garbage in old gen in order to make room for the next set of promoted garbage from a subsequent read.

In 3.6, you'll likely see a [stop-gap](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11206) meant to be temporary until CASSANDRA-9754 is finished.

Comment: my replication_factor is 3

Comment: gc info in system.log INFO  [Service Thread] 2016-04-12 10:38:15,825 GCInspector.java:278 - ParNew GC in 7860ms.  CMS Old Gen: 5331043280 -> 5331554336; Par Eden Space: 2577006592 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 2984416 -> 2590626

Comment: A 7.8 second ParNew is a pretty clear sign you're in a bad place in terms of garbage collection. You may need to consider raising your new generation size (or even new gen and max heap size), or fixing your data model - your partitions are too large, and that's not going to behave properly in 2.x

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8150 has some other really helpful GC tuning ideas. Many are covered in Al's 2.1 tuning guide.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your kernel version.  You may be hitting the java futex_wait bug described [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64/BonaHiVbEmsJ).

Comment: thanks, I've check this and updated the kernel, but it seems not relevant

Comment: I uploaded more pictures.